# Loop through each instance of a class in php

Tags: php

How would I go about looping through each instance of a class based on the given code:

```
class Project {
    // Constructor
    public function __construct($projectTitle, $projectSummary, $projectTools) {
        $this->projectTitle = $projectTitle;
        $this->projectSummary = $projectSummary;
        $this->projectTools = $projectTools;
    }
```

I had created the following public function:

```
public function displayProjectCard() {
        echo '<div class="card mt-4 w-75" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">' . $this->projectTitle . '</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">' . $this->projectSummary . '</p>
                    <p class="tools">' . $this->projectTools . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
```

...but I'm not sure how - or if it's possible - to loop through each class instance so that each "projectCard" is displayed in it's own Bootstrap card.

The instances have been created like:

```
$project1 = new Project(
            "Project Title", 
            "This is where you'll write a description of your project and related features.", 
            "Tools", 
        );
```

The goal is to have the outcome look like:

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYnrT.png)

Comment: you can create multiple instances of your object using a loop, `foreach`, `for`, or whichever loop construct you prefer

Comment: Are the ```Project``` instances in an array?

Comment: The instances aren't in an array. They just look like:

$project1 = new Project(
            "Project Title", 
            "This is where you'll write a description of your project and related features.", 
            "Tools", 

        );

Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: @mkb, so what the problem to store all your instances in one simple array?

Comment: In a separate file I did try to do this with an array as well, however I couldn't figure out how to style each key in the array differently. I'll add and image to the post to show what it should end up looking like.

Comment: What you've shown seems fine. What you haven't shown is anything about multiple instances of your object. If they're not in some sort of iterable container (like an array), then you're not going to be able to iterate over them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your code, I would approach it something like this:

```
// instantiate projects array like this
$projects = array(
    new Project("Title1", "Summary", "Tools"),
    new Project("Title2", "Summary", "Tools"),
    new Project("Title3", "Summary", "Tools"),
    new Project("Title3", "Summary", "Tools"),
);

// then iterate each $projects and then call the displayProjectCard()
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $project->displayProjectCard();
}
```

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'm new to php and have spent two days trying to figure this out. So helpful!

Comment: Sorry but there are some syntax errors on your code. There are extra "," inside each class instantiation and instead of finishing the lines with ";" you should use ","

Comment: @andergmartins, that slipped my mind, I have updated the code above to fix the error `There are extra "," inside each class instantiation and instead of finishing the lines with ";" you should use ","`

Comment: Cool, sounds good, tks. I saw I had duplicated the answer so I just removed mine ;)

Comment: @DrakulaPredator yes, I do now.